# Power BI - Shape map rendering issues with TopoJSON

Tags: powerbi, topojson

I need to attach a TopoJSON file to the shape map in Power BI.

My shapefile after converting in https://mapshaper.org/ is not displayed correctly in the Power BI - the Picasso effect.

The source of the shapefile is
http://gdz.bkg.bund.de/index.php/default/open-data/verwaltungsgebiete-1-250-000-mit-einwohnerzahlen-ebenen-stand-31-12-vg250-ew-ebenen-31-12.html

I tried the methods:

- in QGIS set the projection wgs84 → export to .shp → export from maphaper to TopoJSON
- export to mapshaper → change projection in mapshaper → export to TopoJSON
- change the projection in the mapmapshaper ‘proj wgs84 -o’ → export to a new .shp → upload  in the mapshaper → export to TopoJSON

The result of all these manipulations is one - the Picasso effect after connecting to Power BI.

[image]

[image]

How can I correctly upload the municipalities of Germany to Shape Map in Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that when you load the shp into Qgis, there is no coordinate transformation problem. I got this message when I upload your file to Qgis.[image]

Moreover, Also check that your layer in Qgis has a correct SRC (because Qgis can display layers without the SRC being correct).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my case resolve using this steps:

1. In Mapshaper, open console e use this comand: `proj wgs84 -o`
2. A new file will be downloaded to your machine.
3. Reload page and upload this new archive
4. Export in TopoJson

In other cases, you may use `proj albersusa -o` on first step;

For me worked this steps, but have a QGis solution, if you want, [follow this link](https://dataveld.com/2016/09/01/overcoming-potential-power-bi-shape-map-rendering-issues/)